# Save image url to database after upload

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I upload an image from a react native expo app.

In the back end, I have this code :

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
 
    callback(null, "avatars");
  },

  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    let imagePath = Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname);
    callback(null, imagePath);


  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.use("/uploadAvatar", upload.single("avatar"), (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json("Image enregistrée !");
});
```

It works fine and save the image into a folder.
What I need to do, is to save the image path in the database.

The image is an avatar for a user profile, so I need to add its path to the user table.

Comment: Inspect `req.file`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are storing the image in your middleware:

```js
app.use('/uploadAvatar', upload.single('avatar'), async (req, res) => {
  // Assume that you're storing the image with a function,
  // in this case you just need to pass the filename into
  // your function. This is a pseudocode and is not expected to work
  // as it is, so please adjust accordingly.
  const result = await storeImage(req.file.filename);

  // Return the response as JSON.
  res.status(200).json('Image enregistrée!');
});
```

Basically, you have to inspect the `req.file` that would be populated after you call the `upload.single('avatar')` middleware. In this case, we're taking the filename to be stored into the database. You can do any path/file/property manipulations that you might want to do before storing that image, though.

For further information about `req.file` and what properties it contains, please see the [Multer documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html).